# JQuery click doesn't always work

Tags: jquery

This is my first time using jQuery and I don't get it why it doesn't work most of the time.

```
<script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="movetop">
  <i id="pushtop" class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pushtop').click(function(){
    $(window).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

This works like 2% of the time. It appears to be the `click` keyword.

Comment: There's nothing about this which would not work. If it only works some of the time but not others then the problem isn't your code. Is the `jQuery.js` file being served properly? Are you adding the `#pushtop` element to the DOM dynamically after the page loads? Check the console on occasions it doesn't work.

Comment: try on click @xymenez

Comment: @saurabhkamble That's identical. If `click()` has the issue, so will `on('click', fn)`

Comment: try basic error catching, use console.log inside your click function to test if it's firing

Comment: I've tried using an alter inside the function and it doesn't always work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this instead:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say I'm using fontawesome and that `<i>` tag will be converted into a `<svg>`. I completely forgot about that. I've moved the id to the div instead and it's working perfectly.

Sorry about the confusion.